# how to search a text in a tag class with a python scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to search a text in a tag class in python scraper. For example, I am trying to search this tag:

`<span class="story-author">By Staff</span>`

by only search "author" in my find function like this,

```py
text = soup.find(class_='author')
print(text)
```

however, it did not find this tag and print none. There is any method I can do to fix this

Comment: I advise adding an example of both: 1) the HTML you are trying to parse 2) more of the Python code you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with either contains or ends with operators depending on use case. Required bs4 4.7.0+

```
#ends with
soup.select_one('[class$="author"]')
```

The ends with if must end with that string as per your example html.

```
#contains
soup.select_one('[class*="author"]')
```

The contains if `author` can appear anywhere in class attribute value. `select_one` returns first match. Use `select` if after multiple.

Comment: Since OP probably only wants one tag `soup.select_one` is more appropriate since `soup.select` will return a list. Important to note that in addition to returning a list this will match any tag with a class containing/ending with "author". Don't know how important this is but that particular CSS selector is only available in BeatifulSoup4 >= version 4.7.0, also bs4 uses Soup Sieve to implement the selectors check out https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/ for their docs

Comment: @R.Arctor Thanks. I think the contains version may be a risk. The ends with seems to match with requirement as explained in question. Definitely edit to select_one and will add bs4 v caveat.

Comment: Yeah the contains could definitely throw some false matches. Could also specify to only search span tags with `'span[class$="author"]'`. Don't know if that's necessary though.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do while still using bs4's `find` method and using python3's regex module `re`

```py
import re
soup.find(class_=re.compile(r'.*author.*'))
```

`soup.find` accepts compiled regex and returns the first match to that regex. So this just searches for some html class which contains the text author.

As for the regular expression portion, if you don't already know, periods in python regex match anything once and asterisks say match the preceding character zero or more times. So what that regex string says is match any string which contains the substring `author`.